# How to run multiple C codes on Clion?

Tags: c, clion

This is my first question, so I'll try to explain everything about my problem. So, I had downloaded Clion to code my first C programs for my university degree. So, when I create a simple Hello World on C, I can run normally, but if I create a new program or a new hello world, the program fails with the following error on Clion:

```
> ====================[ Build | MeusCodigosC_2_0 | Debug ]======================== "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion
> 2020.2.1\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build "C:\Users\salom\CLionProjects\MeusCodigosC 2.0\cmake-build-debug"
> --target MeusCodigosC_2_0 -- -j 12 Scanning dependencies of target MeusCodigosC_2_0 [ 33%] Building C object
> CMakeFiles/MeusCodigosC_2_0.dir/AtividadeProducaoLabU2.c.obj [ 66%]
> Building C object CMakeFiles/MeusCodigosC_2_0.dir/HelloWorld.c.obj
> [100%] Linking C executable MeusCodigosC_2_0.exe
> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
> CMakeFiles\MeusCodigosC_2_0.dir/objects.a(HelloWorld.c.obj): na
> funÃ§Ã£o "main": C:/Users/salom/CLionProjects/MeusCodigosC
> 2.0/HelloWorld.c:7: mÃºltiplas definiÃ§Ãµes de "main"; CMakeFiles\MeusCodigosC_2_0.dir/objects.a(AtividadeProducaoLabU2.c.obj):C:/Users/salom/CLionProjects/MeusCodigosC
> 2.0/AtividadeProducaoLabU2.c:32: definido primeiro aqui collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status mingw32-make.exe[3]: ***
> [MeusCodigosC_2_0.exe] Error 1 mingw32-make.exe[2]: ***
> [CMakeFiles/MeusCodigosC_2_0.dir/all] Error 2 mingw32-make.exe[1]: ***
> [CMakeFiles/MeusCodigosC_2_0.dir/rule] Error 2 mingw32-make.exe: ***
> [MeusCodigosC_2_0] Error 2
> CMakeFiles\MeusCodigosC_2_0.dir\build.make:119: recipe for target
> 'MeusCodigosC_2_0.exe' failed CMakeFiles\Makefile2:94: recipe for
> target 'CMakeFiles/MeusCodigosC_2_0.dir/all' failed
> CMakeFiles\Makefile2:101: recipe for target
> 'CMakeFiles/MeusCodigosC_2_0.dir/rule' failed Makefile:137: recipe for
> target 'MeusCodigosC_2_0' failed
```

I checked my CMakeLists.txt which I read that it's the file that makes your codes run, and the new code was already added to the target, but I still can't run it. The only workaround I had found is to delete the old code that I'm not using, and leave it only the code I want to use in that specific moment, only then I can run my C codes on Clion. Anyone had already face an issue like this? Thank you!

Comment: Could you share your CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Sure! There you have it:

`cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(MeusCodigosC_2_0 C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(MeusCodigosC_2_0 AtividadeProducaoLabU2.c)`

The folders and program names are in portuguese, so don't worry about it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The error message says (if I understand Portuguese correctly) that the compiled files have several `main` functions defined in them.

`main()` is the function that runs when your program is executed. Several functions with the same name mean that the compiler doesn't know which one you want to run.

If you are writing several different programs, just keep them in separate folders, or make sure your `CMakeLists.txt` includes only one of them.

UPD: It looks like CLion supports one project creating multiple executable files. See [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-cmake-tutorial.html#addtargets-reload).

In your case, `CMakeFile.txt` should probably contain two lines (file names might need to be corrected):

> add_executable(hello_world HelloWorld.c)
>
> add_executable(MeusCodigosC_2_0 AtividadeProducaoLabU2.c)

If HelloWorld and Lab2 should share some code, you may extract it to a separate file, e.g. `common.c`, then update the project to say

> add_executable(hello_world HelloWorld.c common.c)
>
> add_executable(MeusCodigosC_2_0 AtividadeProducaoLabU2.c common.c)

Comment: When you say separate folders, do you mean a different project on Clion? Isn't there any way to run multiple programs using the `main()` function without crashing? That's right, the name of the files and folders are in portuguese

Comment: If I understood correctly, if the file does not share any code with the other file, I can't run them simultaneously on Clion. The right way would be create a new project and then add the `add_executable()` in the `CMakeFile.txt` adding the new project and file as you explained in the second example on the update, am I correct?

Comment: @Sal you may create a second project, or just have two `add_executable` lines in one project, however you prefer.

Comment: Hi @IMil, Thanks for the explanation. I'll give it a try and see how it goes. Thanks again!

PS: Sorry for the delay in my reply, university assignments and all :(

Answer (score -3):

[image]

I had this problem in clion and i fixed that. I Just opened new project and ta damm it worked.
it seems so easy to fix but my first time to using this so it was hard little bit for me :)

Comment: If you remove the irritating screenshot, and if you elaborate more on the **exact** reason and how to correct it, your answer will be much better.